# Undesired and unstable rise in output read voltage of sensors when more components attached to Arduino circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage, motor, sensor, solenoid

I am making a project which has one air pump run by a L293D motor controller, a few solenoid valves running at 6 volts, and sensors.

The air pump and the valves are powered through a 6 volt adapter.

Curiously, the design I am following asks for shorting the ground of the Arduino with the negative of the adaptor and the ground on the motor controller with the negative of the adaptor, which I did.

Before I connected the motor and the solenoids, my sensors (powered through 5V Arduino, Arduino ground, 3.3 V Arduino for reference) were working fine. Now after connecting the motor and the solenoids and the adaptor they are most of the time giving highly fluctuating readings which are generally off by a margin of 5 ADC values or more.

I noticed that first I had set the high/low for the valves digitalwrite in the void setup, and when I removed them from there and added them to the loop function as and when needed, the beginning values from the sensor corrected slightly although not entirely, but now when the loop runs the values are off again.

I do not understand why this is happening.  There is no connection between the sensors and the adaptor/motor/solenoids except sharing a common ground and of course the same board (Arduino UNO)for points.

My understanding of capacitor circuit after power supply as suggested by @Antonio51

[image: My understanding of capacitor circuit after power supply as suggested by @Antonio51]

Comment: How did you connect "physically" the "grounds" ? Show a picture of wiring, please?

Comment: @Antonio51 My wiring is on a solderless breadboard (lets call it BB1), it is a jungle over here, if you would insist then I would upload. What I did was basically directly insert the positive and negative wires of the adapter into the side rail of the breadboard, then inserted the ground and power of the L293D motor controller into the same rail using jumper cables. Then I took another jumper cable (lets call it JC1), placed one end into the negative rail, and the other end into the GND of the Arduino.          ...cont.inued ahead..

Comment: @Antonio51 Arduino UNO has two GNDs pin points in the analogue pins side, in one I inserted other end of JC1, in the other I inserted another jumper (call it JC2) which is going into the ground side rail of another breadboard (call it BB2) (the other rail of BB2 is connected to 5V of Arduino) which has my sensors on it. At first I had connected the other end of JC1 into the ground rail of BB2 thinking that since this rail is connected to ground of arduino it should work, but then the ADC figures were off by nearly 20, so I disconnected from BB2 and put it directly into the Arduino.

Comment: Ok. Electrical wiring is "theoretically" correct, but probably very noisy for Arduino and sensors. I should suggest supplying air pump, and solenoids separately from Arduino and sensors, and making only "one" connection between the two systems. Use also some capacitors for decoupling "supplies", especially supplying air pump and solenoids. Note that if the supply voltage for Arduino is also the "reference" for the ADC, you should measure also the "true" value" of this reference to correct ADC values.

Comment: See this for example  https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-know-vcc-voltage-in-arduino/344001/2  You should also take some measurements (at 1..10 ms intervals) and apply "mean" voltage.

Comment: @Antonio51 Need clarity about what you mean by supplying solenoids and Arduino separately. I am already powering the motor and solenoids by the adaptor, and powering  Arduino and sensors through the cable connected to my laptop.

Comment: @Antonio51 Please also clarify how to use capacitors to decouple supplies of air pump and solenoids. Right now my motor and solenoid are pinned into the side rails of BB1 which are powered +ve and -ve by the adapter wires.

Comment: Ok for the supply of Arduino by laptop. Add to the other supply at least 2 capacitors (100 nF paralleled with 100 uF) to suppress most "transients". Wires as short as possible.

Comment: Note also that solenoids (and perhaps pump) must use a "freewheel" diode for BackEMF when switching off ...

Comment: Actually, fluctuation of ADC by 5 in 10-bit Arduino ADC (1023 max; ~0.005*5V~=0.025V=25mV) sounds perfectly normal, especially given the whole thing is on a breadboard. Common practice is to take average of several samples or filter incoming data some other way. You can only expect so much from the breadboard, where wires pick up stuff from all over the place and ground currents all get mixed together.

Comment: @Antonio51 I think I am understanding what you are saying. I am already using a 1A IN4007 diode for my solenoids, but I was not using any capacitors in the path of my adaptor power supply. Thanks for the tip, if I understand it correctly, I should put the supply, the capacitors and the rest all in parallel relative to each other?

Comment: @Antonio51 One more thing, my solenoids are getting hot on application, is that normal? I am using two types of solenoids (6V and 5V), one I am using within voltage range, the other (5V) I am using at a slightly higher voltage than its range (its range is 4-6V, I am using it at 6.7V) as within the range the response wasn't good, and both are getting hot.

Comment: @Ilya thanks, I'll try the averaging method. Can you suggest how to filter?

Comment: Some solenoids can be "hot" if they are functioning for a long time, especially some of bad quality and not well dimensioned for "heat".

Comment: You could also try staggering your digital output switching; Arduinos can have atrociously bad ground bounce: https://www.signalintegrityjournal.com/blogs/12-fundamentals/post/1207-seven-habits-of-successful-2-layer-board-designers

Comment: @vir this article is very informative. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks. I have updated my question and uploaded the circuit with the supply part of capacitors which you suggested. I am an amateur in electronics, can you please confirm if I have got it right? Also can you please suggest which type I would need? There is a lot on the internet, electrolytic, ceramic etc etc

Comment: 100 uF should be electrolytic or tantalum. 100 nF are plastic named MKH or MKT, don't remember, with short wires ...

Comment: @Antonio51 Absolutely, with short wires. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As for (software side) filtering, you can try various methods, take average of 5 measurements, or take 10 measurements, remove outliers and take average of the rest or something. Totally up to you. Of course if sensor output changes a lot and quickly, taking many measurements and averaging them can ruin it. There is no proper solution, just whatever reduces impact of individual outlier measurement. This is regarding software side. Regarding hardware side, you're already talking capacitors.

Comment: @Ilya Thanks. One question, is my ground pin when not placed into GND rail supposed to shock when no power source is connected? Does this mean there is some capacitance building up in the system even though no capacitors are currently connected? Is this healthy?

Comment: It means there is a difference in charge between you and ground level of the device and for the short moment when you touch it, the charge between you and GND pin equalizes with very high current. Do some research on ESD/static charge safety when handling electronics, that's what it's about.

Comment: @Ilya Oho...ok will do, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ADCs in a system with multiple loads great attention needs to be given to the path of ground currents.  If ground return current from a load flows through part of a ground path for a sensor or signal source then the ground conductor drop will affect the ADC reading. I have observed the sort of variations that you describe in similar applications.

As well as filter capacitors, as mentioned in comments, you should try to "star" your ground paths from a single point as much as possible. I have found that doing this rigorously can substantially reduce ADC variations caused by high power loads ground return currents.